# Converting Raw(16) to GUID

Tags: sql, oracle, guid

Is there a way to create an `SQL` script that will convert a list of Oracle `RAW(16)` to `GUID`?

I need to find a simple and fast way to convert about 14 million items. I have exported the list to several delimited files and I am able to import this data into a schema.

Answer (score 9):

A `RAW(16)` basically *is* a GUID: it's a 16-byte hex value. So one option is to just leave it alone. Oracle will implicitly cast between character and hex, so if you're looking for a row whose raw value is `FE2BF132638011E3A647F0DEF1FEB9E8`, you can use a string in your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myRaw16Column = 'FE2BF132638011E3A647F0DEF1FEB9E8';
```

If you want to change the `RAW(16)` to `CHAR(32)` for your conversion you can use `RAWTOHEX` as @tbone suggests.

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (myGUIDColumn, ...)
  SELECT RAWTOHEX(myRawColumn), ...
  FROM OldTable
```

If you want to make it a `CHAR(36)` dash-formatted GUID, things get complicated quickly:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (myGUIDColumn, ...)
  SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(myRaw16Column, '(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)', '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5'), ...
  FROM OldTable
```

Comment: Is myGUIDColumn a Char(32) Data Type? I do also need it in a dash-formatted GUID.

Comment: The `RAWTOHEX` example shows how to change a `RAW(16)` to an unformatted GUID, which is `CHAR(32)`. The `REGEXP_REPLACE` example shows how to change a `RAW(16)` to a dash-formatted GUID, which is `CHAR(36)`.  Personally, I'd store it as `RAW(16)`, which is what the Oracle `SYS_GUID()` function returns, and format it for display as needed. But that's just my preference. As the first example in my answer shows, you can query for a GUID value in a `RAW(16)` column without having to resort to any special tricks.

Comment: Thanks Ed. 

I have about 14 million files that I need to delete from UNIX and currently the only way that I can identify them is by the file name. The file name looks like this. 

FN{FFEF5B84-D2ED-45E3-9BD6-5C368357428A}{6A6CF41E-BE0F-4892-9808-34EDDD802300}-0.pdf

This first GUID is the Object_ID and the second GUID is object storage identifier. However, the database list these in the RAW(16) format. I currently have a full list of the filest that need to be deleted but the Object_ID is in RAW(16) format. If I can convert the Object_ID to a GUID then I can create a list of files.

Comment: Got it. I thought you needed to move the value from one table to another, hence the `INSERT ... SELECT`. Sorry about the confusion. You can use the `REGEXP_REPLACE` to get your filename, something like: `SELECT FN{' || REGEXP_REPLACE(Object_ID, '(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)', '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5') || '}{' || REGEXP_REPLACE(Object_Storage_ID, '(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)', '\1-\2-\3-\4-\5') || '}-0.pdf' FROM myTable...`